Trying to extrude a path\plane\road into a mountain - but it doesn't work as expected
would really appreciate understanding what I am doing wrong here. I imported the mountain from touchterrain.geol.iastate.edu and created the path from an svg file that I generated using Inkscape. I then used all the modifiers that you can see in the video and tried to extrude my plane into the mountain and then use a boolean modifier on the mountain - but it doesn't seem to work as expected.


Hello, so what are you trying to do exactly?

Could you show us the "Face Orientation" (the blue/red "thing") after applying all the modifiers ?

@StefLAncien nice catch! It was a big portion of the problem, but I still have "holes" where the boolean modifier doesn't work where it seems to suppose to work? https://imgur.com/a/4xmf1lN

You can try and play with the "Solver Options".
